# Why sudo isn't acceptable?

Tags: linux, command-line, setcap

I need to create a network bridge with 'brctl addbr br-lan' command in a sh script without using sudo.

I have a script like;

```
brctl addbr br-lan
ifconfig lo up
```

I have tried to set capabilities to my script with

```
sudo ./setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin,cap_dac_override+eip 
./myscript.sh
```

But it didn't change anything.

To call './myscript.sh' returns the following output;

```
add bridge failed: Operation not permitted
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
```

What should I do to run my script without root rights or which capabilities should I define to my script?

Tx.

Comment: Did you knew that sudo has fine-grained permissions. E.g. you can give one user permission to do one thing (with or without password). It is **not all or nothing**.

Comment: Why won't you consider using `sudo`?

Comment: You should state your goal in addition to the mean, this is to avoid an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). There are other methods. For example you can ask the part of your system handling network to setup the bridge, without this script. etc. We don't know why you want to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign capabilities to a script, because it's the interpreter that requires them, not the script. If you can't use `sudo` you need to find some other way of running the script with root privileges.

Perhaps if you update your question to include some context (for example, mentioning why you can't use `sudo`, or why the script won't be naturally run under a root account) someone here might be able to provide some additional suggestions.

Comment: As you say I can not set capabilities to my .sh script and now I am trying to set capabilities to ifconfig and brctl commands that is used in the sh script.

Comment: If you add capabilities to those commands you will enable ANY USER on your system to run them. That's a really bad idea. Really bad. Why not edit your question to explain why `sudo` isn't acceptable - because it's by far the easiest option on the table.

Comment: So what if I compile my own ifconfig and brctl codes and give them that capabilities is it bad idea too ?

Comment: Yes it's a really bad idea. Why won't you consider using `sudo`? Both of us here are telling you the same thing.

Comment: Platform dependency is my reason to use the setcap method.As you say I am going to try to set capabilities to just my executable files. Also, thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

- Did you knew that sudo has fine-grained permissions. E.g. you can give one user permission to do one thing (with or without password). It is **not all or nothing**.
- Consider writing in `go`lang or other high-level, compiled language. It will allow capabilities.
- Consider using `docker` and giving some `sudo` privileges to manage this container. Beware container/image renames, may allow privilege escalation (not all containers/images with this name are the same), so beware of what you allow.