# How to compile the libcap for cross-platform

Tags: cross-compilation

I have a question about the library that I downloaded from the following URL;
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/morgan/libcap.git/
And that's version is 2.26.
I need to compile and run the library for my ARM platform. The lib compiled well but when it runs with “./setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin,cap_dac_override+eip ./my.elf” command it returns me the “error while loading shared libraries: libcap.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory” error.
Also, it works well for my pc build.
I think the libcap.so.2 file is linked from the /lib directory to the setcap file so when I try to run it on my ARM platform, it returns me the libcap.so.2 error because there is no libcap.so file in my cross-platforms's lib direction.
To fix the problem I think the libcap.so file should be linked that is in the library direction.(maybe that is wrong idea).
Do you have any idea about the problem?

Comment: You're still trying to solve the [wrong problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497982/why-sudo-isnt-acceptable#comment916825_497982)? Good luck with that.

Comment: No. I found the response of the wrong problem.First answer that accepted is my solution for the problem.